# Movesense App with Android Studio is crashing everytime

Tags: java, android, android-studio, movesense

I try to programm an App for the Movesense Device and tried to rebuild the code which is on their official homepage. The Problem ist that the App is crashing, after I push den Scan button. I hope you can help me. I tried to download different dagger version  and searched for the causes:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbleshadow/dagger/internal/Preconditions

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bleshadow.dagger.internal.Preconditions" on path

but that didn't really helped me and before I forget - I'm a beginner.

ErrorCode:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.medtec, PID: 12232
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbleshadow/dagger/internal/Preconditions;
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.DaggerClientComponent$Builder.applicationContext(DaggerClientComponent.java:412)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.DaggerClientComponent$Builder.applicationContext(DaggerClientComponent.java:399)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.RxBleClient.create(RxBleClient.java:54)
        at com.example.medtec.MainActivity.getBleClient(MainActivity.java:73)
        at com.example.medtec.MainActivity.onScanClicked(MainActivity.java:105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bleshadow.dagger.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~SfZrrIGMBCbREFrH06uGZA==/com.example.medtec-upuErZzA2C5EqBajJNc57Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~SfZrrIGMBCbREFrH06uGZA==/com.example.medtec-upuErZzA2C5EqBajJNc57Q==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~SfZrrIGMBCbREFrH06uGZA==/com.example.medtec-upuErZzA2C5EqBajJNc57Q==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.DaggerClientComponent$Builder.applicationContext(DaggerClientComponent.java:412) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.DaggerClientComponent$Builder.applicationContext(DaggerClientComponent.java:399) 
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.RxBleClient.create(RxBleClient.java:54) 
        at com.example.medtec.MainActivity.getBleClient(MainActivity.java:73) 
        at com.example.medtec.MainActivity.onScanClicked(MainActivity.java:105) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the application in the simulator instead of actual Android device. MDS does not support actual operation on x86 hardware, only ARM.

Connect a phone using USB cable and make sure that the phone has USB debugging enabled.

*Full disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*